# Why do my program prints None in the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, linked-list

I'm learning algorithms and data structures by my own and want to write a program that merges two linked lists in the following way: given two integers a and b it will remove nodes from a-*th* to b-*th* from the first linked list and insert second linked list in their place.

I took an implementation of linked list from [here](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/linked-lists-in-python) and wrote a function

```
def merge(list1: LinkedList, a: int, b: int, list2: LinkedList) -> LinkedList:

    current = list1.head
    previous = None
    insertion = list2.head
    counter = 0

    while insertion.next_node:
        insertion = insertion.next_node

    while current:
        if counter == a:
            previous.next_node = list2.head
        elif counter == b:
            insertion.next_node = current.next_node
        previous = current
        counter += 1
        current = current.next_node

    return list1.printList()
```

This is the complete code of the resulting program:

```
class Node(object):
 
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node
 
 
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
 
    def size(self):
     current = self.head
     count = 0
     while current:
        count += 1
        current = current.next_node
     return count
       
    def printList(self): 
        temp = self.head 
        while (temp): 
            print (temp.data, " -> ", end = '') 
            temp = temp.next_node
        print("")
 
    def insert_at_head(self, data):
      new_node = Node(data)
      new_node.next_node = self.head
      self.head = new_node
 
    def get_next_node (self,node):
      return node.next_node.data

list1 = LinkedList(Node(0))
s = list1.head
for i in range(1,6):
    s.next_node = Node(i)
    s = s.next_node
list1.printList()

list2 = LinkedList(Node(99))
w = list2.head
for j in range(98,96,-1):
    w.next_node = Node(j)
    w = w.next_node
list2.printList()

def merge(list1: LinkedList, a: int, b: int, list2: LinkedList) -> LinkedList:

    current = list1.head
    previous = None
    insertion = list2.head
    counter = 0

    while insertion.next_node:
        insertion = insertion.next_node

    while current:
        if counter == a:
            previous.next_node = list2.head
        elif counter == b:
            insertion.next_node = current.next_node
        previous = current
        counter += 1
        current = current.next_node

    return list1.printList()

print(merge(list1, 1, 3, list2))
```

It works as expected except only it prints an additional None in the end of an output. Why does it print None? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line prints the *return* of your `merge` call. The return of `merge` is `list.printList()`. However, `list.printList()` doesn't have a return defined, so it defaults to `None`. Note that `list.printList()` still *prints* when called; it just doesn't have a defined *return*.

Sounds like you just want to call `merge` without the printing. So the last line could be:

```
merge(list1, 1, 3, list2)
```